# Flex Image source event, How to know when the new source is received?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, events

I have a simple Image component,
I change its source dynamically on creation.

```
myimg.source = "http://foo/bar.jpg"
```

How can I know when the image is loaded and received so that I can check its width ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you are working with flex:
Set a render event on your image component:

```
<mx:Image id="theImage" render="yourFunction(event)"/>
```

In the script field:

```
private function yourFunction(evt:Event){
var theWidth= (evt.target as Image).width;
}
```

The render event is called when any displayobject is dispatched when the display list is about to be updated and rendered.

Flash (AS3.0):

```
//constructor function
public function CustomDisplayObject() {
theImage.addEventListener(Event.RENDER, renderHandler);
}

private function renderHandler(evt:Event):void {
var theWidth:int = evt.width;
}
```

(only tested in flex)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add an event listener to the images [event.creationComplete](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:creationComplete) event to know when it's done being loaded. Or maybe it's [event.progress](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#event:progress). I'd take a look at the [inherited events](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Image.html#eventSummary) on the Image control and see which works.